# java.util.TreeMap$Entry.entrySet() is applicable for argument types: () values: []

Tags: java, groovy

I have `ChatDayWrappers` which contains all messages in the database between the two parties for one day.

How can I get the the chatRowWrappers with the 47 items from the object `chatWrapper.getChatDayWrappers()[0];`?

**Code**

```
Object object = chatWrapper.getChatDayWrappers()[0];            
getLogger().info("chatWrapper:  " + object.getClass().getName());
```

**output**

```
java.util.TreeMap$Entry
```

**Another try:**

I have tired the following:

```
Object object[] = chatWrapper.getChatDayWrappers()[0].entrySet().toArray();             
getLogger().info("chatWrapper:  " + object.getClass().getName());
```

but I got this error:

> No signature of method: java.util.TreeMap$Entry.entrySet() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
>   Possible solutions: every(): groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.TreeMap$Entry.entrySet() is applicable for argument types: () values: []

**CockpitChatWrapper**

```
public class CockpitChatWrapper
        implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static final String STYLE_CHAT_UNKNOWN = "tpChatUnknown";
    public static final String STYLE_CHAT_FROM = "tpChatFrom";
    public static final String STYLE_CHAT_TO = "tpChatTo";

    /** Used to format the dates in the report. */
    private static final ThreadLocal<SimpleDateFormat> DATE_FORMAT = new ThreadLocal<SimpleDateFormat>() {

        @Override
        protected SimpleDateFormat initialValue() {
            return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        }
    };

    private final Map<String, ChatDisplayDayWrapper> chatDayWrappers;

    private final Long currentUserId;
    private final Long currentFlexiObjectId;


    /**
     * Constructor.
     * 
     * @param currentUserId The user Id.
     * @param currentFlexiObjectId The flexiObejct Id.
     */
    public CockpitChatWrapper(final Long currentUserId, final Long currentFlexiObjectId) {
        this.chatDayWrappers = new TreeMap<String, ChatDisplayDayWrapper>(new Comparator<String>() {

            public int compare(final String o1, final String o2) {
                return (o1.compareTo(o2) * -1);
            }

        });
        this.currentUserId = currentUserId;
        this.currentFlexiObjectId = currentFlexiObjectId;
    }


    /**
     * 
     * Add a chat entry.
     * 
     * @param chat The chat entry.
     */
    public void addChatEntry(final Chat chat) {

        String key = CockpitChatWrapper.DATE_FORMAT.get().format(chat.getLastWrite());
        ChatDisplayDayWrapper entry = null;
        if (this.chatDayWrappers.get(key) != null) {
            entry = this.chatDayWrappers.get(key);
        } else {
            entry = new ChatDisplayDayWrapper(chat.getLastWrite());
            this.chatDayWrappers.put(key, entry);
        }

        entry.addChat(chat, this.currentUserId, this.currentFlexiObjectId);
    }


    /**
     * Returns the chatDayWrappers.
     * 
     * @return Returns the chatDayWrappers.
     */
    public Object[] getChatDayWrappers() {
        return this.chatDayWrappers.entrySet().toArray();
    }


    public boolean getHasChatDayWrappers() {
        return this.chatDayWrappers != null && this.chatDayWrappers.size() > 0;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * Hold the chat entries for an day.
     * 
     */
    public static class ChatDisplayDayWrapper
            implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private final Date day;
        private final List<ChatDisplayRowWrapper> chatRowWrappers;


        /**
         * 
         * Constructor.
         * 
         * @param day The day to set.
         */
        public ChatDisplayDayWrapper(final Date day) {
            this.day = day;
            this.chatRowWrappers = new ArrayList<ChatDisplayRowWrapper>();
        }


        private void addChat(final Chat chat, final Long currentUserId, final Long currentFlexiObjectId) {

            String styleClass = CockpitChatWrapper.STYLE_CHAT_UNKNOWN;

            if (currentUserId != null && chat.getFromUser() != null
                    && currentUserId.longValue() == chat.getFromUser().getId().longValue()) {
                styleClass = CockpitChatWrapper.STYLE_CHAT_FROM;
            } else if (currentFlexiObjectId != null && chat.getFromFlexiObject() != null
                    && currentFlexiObjectId.longValue() == chat.getFromFlexiObject().getId().longValue()) {
                styleClass = CockpitChatWrapper.STYLE_CHAT_TO;
            }
            this.chatRowWrappers.add(new ChatDisplayRowWrapper(chat, styleClass));
        }


        /**
         * Returns the day.
         * 
         * @return Returns the day.
         */
        public Date getDay() {
            return this.day;
        }


        /**
         * Returns the chatRowWrappers.
         * 
         * @return Returns the chatRowWrappers.
         */
        public List<ChatDisplayRowWrapper> getChatRowWrappers() {
            return this.chatRowWrappers;
        }

    }

}
```

**screenshot**

[image]

Comment: can you add the code for the class of chatWrapper object as well?

Comment: @Maddy: I have add the class of `private CockpitChatWrapper chatWrapper;`

Comment: If you would declare a proper return type instead of `Object[]` your IDE would help out a little bit better.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is:

```
public Object[] getChatDayWrappers() {
        return this.chatDayWrappers.entrySet().toArray();
    }
```

returns an Object array that you cannot directly access the ChatDisplayDayWrapper object inside the map. Instead, you could modify your getter to:

```
public List<ChatDisplayRowWrapper> getChatDayWrappers() {
    return m.entrySet().stream().map(entry -> entry.getValue()).collect(Collectors.toList());        }
}
```

Comment: I have tried it but I got ' No signature of method: de.tp.em.frontend.jsf.cockpit.chat.CockpitChatWrapper.getChatDayWrappers() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [2017-11-27]'

Comment: what is the data type of the key in Map<key, value>?

Comment: I have tried your last Code and I got ` No signature of method: [Ljava.lang.Object;.get() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [2017-11-27]
Possible solutions: getAt(java.lang.String), grep(), grep(), getAt(groovy.lang.IntRange), getAt(java.util.Collection), getAt(groovy.lang.Range)`

Comment: are you sure the formatted string used to create the key is the same as the formatted string used to get the value?

Comment: I can Access it like this: `chatWrapper.getChatDayWrappers()[0].value.getChatRowWrappers()`

Answer (score 0):

Your function `Object[] getChatDayWrappers`:

```
this.chatDayWrappers.entrySet().toArray()
```

returns an array of `Map$Entry`. E.g.:

```
groovy:000> [1:1].entrySet().toArray().first().getClass()
===> class java.util.LinkedHashMap$Entry
```

An `Entry` is *not* a map, it's just an entry.  An entry holds `key` and `value` (but not `entrySet()`; this is where your code fails).  E.g.

```
groovy:000> [1:1].entrySet().toArray().first().key
===> 1
groovy:000> [1:1].entrySet().toArray().first().value
===> 1
groovy:000> [1:1].entrySet().toArray().first().entrySet()
ERROR groovy.lang.MissingMethodException:
No signature of method: java.util.LinkedHashMap$Entry.entrySet() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: every()
```

So to get the display wrapper you need to call `value` in Groovy, or since your code looks more like Java anyway `.getValue()` to get the `ChatDisplayDayWrapper`.