# Sort Object[] with TreeMap.Entry

Tags: java, groovy

I have a list of type `Object[]` inside it are `TreeMap.Entry<String, ChatDisplayDayWrapper>`.

The key is a  string like `2017-11-28`, `2017-11-27`, `2017-11-26`.

How can I sort the list to get the keys sorted reversed also
--> `2017-11-26`, `2017-11-27`, `2017-11-28`?

I have tried to convert the `String` to `Date` put I do not know how to write them back after sorting the list.

**Code**

```
Object[] objectList = chatWrapper.getChatDayWrappers(); 

List<Date> listToSort = new ArrayList<Date>();

for (int i = 0; i <= objectList.size() - 1; i++) {
        String day = objectList[i].key;
        Date newDate = dfDate.parse(day);
        listToSort.add(newDate)
}
getLogger().info("before sorting listToSort: " + listToSort);

listToSort = listToSort.sort { a, b ->
    a <=> b 
}
getLogger().info("After sorting listToSort: " + listToSort);
```

**output**

before sorting listToSort:

> [Tue Nov 28 00:00:00 CET 2017, Mon Nov 27 00:00:00 CET 2017, Sun Nov 26 00:00:00 CET 2017]

After sorting listToSort:

> [Sun Nov 26 00:00:00 CET 2017, Mon Nov 27 00:00:00 CET 2017, Tue Nov 28 00:00:00 CET 2017]

**screenshot**

[image]

Comment: What do you want to do after sorting them? Basically want the map to be in sorted order. Is that it?

Comment: A TreeMap is already sorted, so the entries are sorted (from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47516828/java-util-treemapentry-entryset-is-applicable-for-argument-types-values) .  Either reverse your sorting in the map or since you already have fully realized array, reverse that.  Yet going from that `TreeMap` down to `Object[]` does more harm than good...

Answer (score 1):

**Java 8**

```
 List<TreeMap.Entry<String, ChatDisplayDayWrapper>> myList = Arrats.asList(objectList);
 DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd");
    Collections.sort(myList , (s1, s2) -> LocalDateTime.parse(s1.getKey(), formatter).
            compareTo(LocalDateTime.parse(s2.getKey(), formatter)));
```

**Java 7**

```
 List<TreeMap.Entry<String, ChatDisplayDayWrapper>> myList = Arrays.asList(objectList);
 static SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
public static Comparator<TreeMap.Entry<String, ChatDisplayDayWrapper>> myComparator = new Comparator<TreeMap.Entry<String, ChatDisplayDayWrapper>>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(TreeMap.Entry<String, TreeMap.Entry<String, ChatDisplayDayWrapper>>e1, Employee e2) {
        return formatter .parse(s1.getKey()).
            compareTo(formatter .parse(s2.getKey()))
    }
};

    Collections.sort(myList , myComparator);
```

I took it almost from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14451976/how-to-sort-date-which-is-in-string-format-in-java)

Comment: DateTimeFormatter and LocalDateTime are in Java 8 I am working with Java 7

Comment: What about using SimpleDateFormat and Date?

Comment: I tried with this code `    Object[] objectList = chatWrapper.getChatDayWrappers();
    List<TreeMap.Entry<String, ChatDisplayDayWrapper>> myList = Arrays.asList(objectList);
       DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Collections.sort(myList , (s1, s2) -> Date.parse(s1.getKey(), formatter).
       compareTo(Date.parse(s2.getKey(), formatter)));` but I am getting `expecting ')', found ',' @ line 226, column 34. Collections.sort(myList , (s1, s2) -> Date.parse(s1.getKey(), formatter). ^ 1 error `

Comment: @tree man, you need just a tiny java-7 changes. Check update I've posted

Answer (score 0):

Use like following ..
for reverse sorting

```
     Comparator<Date> dateComparator = (a, b)-> a.compareTo(b);
     listToSort.sort(dateComparator.reversed());
```

for Natural sorting

```
     Comparator<Date> dateComparator = (a, b)->a.compareTo(b);
     listToSort .sort(dateComparator);
```